# Python (2.7.8) ImportError: No module named numpy (1.6.1)

Tags: python, numpy

Python and Numpy were working just fine on my remote machine until I installed pygtk, which I was prompted to do for using matplotlib pyplot forwarding.

I used homebrew to install pygtk on my remote machine. Immediately after I ran a previously working code and received the error:

```
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

I used homebrew to uninstall pygtk, and the error didn't go away. I then used homebrew to uninstall and reinstall python (2.7.8), then downloaded and mounted the disk image of numpy (1.6.1) from sourceforge. However the error remains.  Previous searches on SO revealed a mismatch in versions, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. I've also checked that the directory where python is installed is in my PATH environment. I'm not sure what to check or do next. Please advise.

EDIT:
I'm on OS X 10.10.1

Comment: what does `which python ` and `which -a python ` output

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/python` and `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: ok so you have two python installs, try starting a shell with `/usr/bin/python` and then `/usr/local/bin/python` trying to import numpy in each

Comment: Or I can just uninstall one?

Comment: yes I just wanted to see where your packages were getting installed. If you want just remove `/usr/local/bin/python`, then download `get-pip.py` and run `python get-pip.py` and `pip install -U numpy`

Comment: How do I know which version to uninstall? Several versions are listed in both `usr/bin` and `usr/local/bin`. Also, why use pip instead of homebrew?

Comment: because I already told you ;), remove ->  `/usr/local/bin/python`, pip is by far the easiest way to install python packages, if you stick to one way to install you won't be back in the same situation again.